# Revert Back to My Original Windows 7 from Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, partition-recovery, toshiba-laptop

I had Original Windows 7 Home premium installed in my Toshiba laptop. I had to install Windows 8.1 for an application specific use. Instead of selecting custom install, I installed it on top of my Windows 7 in the same drive. Now after rebooting it loads Windows 8.1 and my Windows 7 is gone. Is there any way I can get my Windows 7 back without loosing files and Applications I installed.

For Toshiba laptop they had provided me a Folder called HDDRecovery which they asked me to use when you want to restore. But i feel like if I use that I will loose my old data. Please help me with a solution on this

Comment: Did you make an image backup of the Windows 7 partition before you upgraded? If no, then you are out of luck. You should backup all your personal data first before restoring Windows 7. Applications can be reinstalled.

Comment: I didnt manually create an image backup. Where can I check if there is any image backup is there.

Comment: If you didn't create one there probably isn't one.

Comment: If i download windows 7 home premium and then install it over the windows 8.1 Drive, can i register that back with my serial and then use it as my original windows 7

Comment: [Not sure if this works for W8 or not](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/933168) No way to preserve what was installed in W8, so BACK UP!